# What is the 'optimal' equal-area partition of a circle?

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles, area, combinatorial-geometry

What is the (an?) n-partition of a circle that meets the following criteria:

1. The boundaries of each partition can be represented as a union of finitely many  finite-piecewise-smooth simple closed contours. No weird unrealizable infinite cantor nonsense.
2. The integral over each partition is equal.
3. The sum of arclengths of each smooth contour is minimized

Comment: For huge $n$, say $10^6$, it feels very inefficient to make pie-slices. Instead, pick a tesselation in the interior of the disk, with each tile having the desired area, and then find some way near the boundary of the disk to make irregulat pieces there. That ought to be better than your slices.

Comment: For larger $N$, pie-slices are definitely not optimal. Consider nesting circles. After some algebraic acrobatics we can see that for $N$ circles, the perimeter is of order $1 + \sum_{n=1}^{n=N}\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N}}$

Comment: Yes, your intuition is way off the mark here. Each of your slices has perimeter $\approx 2$. If instead you use hexagons of area $\approx \pi/n$, each hexagon has perimeter $\approx \sqrt[4]{\dfrac{4}{27}}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{n}}$, which is much less for large $n$. You will have problems on the boundary making sure that each partition has the same area, but I think they can be overcome.

Comment: @enthdegree: Didn't you forget a factor of $2\pi$ in your sum? This makes it equal to about $\frac43 \pi n$, which is _worse_ than pie slices.

Comment: If my reasoning is correct, say each circle has radius $r_n$. Then \begin{array}{rl}\pi-\pi r_1^2 &= \\ \pi r_1^2-\pi r_2^2& = \\ \dots & = \\ \pi r_{N-1}^2-\pi r_{N}^2 &= A\end{array} Now $r_1=\sqrt{\pi-A}, r_2=\sqrt{\pi-2A}\dots, r_N=\sqrt{\pi-NA}$, but we know $A=\frac{\pi}{N}$. Now the sum of perimiters is $2\pi + 2\pi \sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N}}$. Each of the sqrt terms is slightly less than 1, so 'eventually' the entire sum should be less than any linear growth.

Comment: Although I am unsure of the details of the last part

Comment: @enthdegree: Well, let's see: we have $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N}} = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\sqrt{\frac{n}{N}} = 1/\sqrt N\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sqrt n$, which is about $1/\sqrt N \cdot  \frac23 \cdot N^{3/2} = \frac23 N$. So my initial estimate was right, I think.

Comment: (Your expressions $r_1 = \sqrt{\pi - A}$ etc. are wrong: they should be $r_1 = \sqrt {1-A/\pi}$ etc.)

Comment: Physically, this is the problem of finding the equilibrium arrangement of $n$ equal-sized bubbles inside a disk, because the surface tension of bubbles acts to minimize the total length of the boundary. So just by physical observation, you can guess that the arrangement will be close to hexagonal, as @TonyK says. I don't expect that a closed-form solution exists.

Comment: See also [honeycomb conjecture (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb_conjecture) where it says that the hexagonal tiling is optimal when filling the entire plane. For a disk, when $n$ from above is great, the "region" close to the boundary/periphery should be relatively unimportant, and we expect most of the area to look very much like the honeycomb. Note: Technically, we should find out if the infimum of the total length of all circumferences is actually attained. If it is, it may well be realized by different configurations (the "the"/"an" distinction of the question).

Comment: @TonyK I understand now, thanks! You're right, my counterexample does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For small numbers of cells $3,4,5,..$ there may be a possibility of finding explicitly the optimal partition (the Y 120 degrees partition in the case $n=3$, etc). For large numbers of cells in the partitions, analytical results are not known. In order to find candidates for the optimal partitions, some numerical studies were performed:

- Cox and Fikkema: [article](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1r45) They studied various polygons and the circle, for up to $42$ cells. The software Evolver was used (specifically designed for the study of bubble configurations). Recently studies were made for bubble configurations up to $200000$ cells ([link](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/frank-morgan/i-win-soap-bubble-cluster_b_1613887.html)). For large numbers of cells, hexagonal configurations are observed. In fact, for $n$ large the configuration converges to the honeycomb, due to the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb_conjecture) of T. Hales.
- E. Oudet: [link](http://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Edouard.Oudet/research/Kelvin/optimal_cutting_n.php) a method based on a relaxation argument. The results are not optimal for large number of phases.
- B. Bogosel: [link](http://www.lama.univ-savoie.fr/~bogosel/partitions_perim_poly.php) a modification of the above method which avoids better the local minima. In particular it obtains similar results to the ones obtained by Cox and Fikkema.